# Acessing Apache Cordova plugins using Typescript

Tags: cordova, typescript, cordova-plugins

I am prototyping an A Hybrid Mobile app using Ionic + Angular + Apache Cordova 4.0 using Visual Studio 2003 update 4. I installed the SQLite plugin to access database.

Recommended method to access this plugin is:

```
var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "my.db"});
```

But I don't have typescript definition for plugin - only Cordova. SO Typescript does not know the sqlitePLugin and its complaining about it.

How do you access Cordova plugin from Typescript code ?
I understand I have to somehow extend the basic "window" object ? How to do that ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

> I understand I have to somehow extend the basic "window" object ? How to do that ?

Here you go:

```
interface Window {
    sqlitePlugin: any;
}

var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: "my.db"});
```

Note: TypeScript interfaces are *open ended* in that their declaration can be re-opened to add members.

Answer (score 3):

The correct way is declaring window out side of class and use it in class (be careful use sqlite after platform ready ! ;) )

```
interface Window {
  sqlitePlugin: any;
}
declare var window : Window;
...
  export class MyClass{

    this.platform.ready().then(() => {

  var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({ name: 'MyDB.db', iosDatabaseLocation: 'default', location: null });
....
});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Typescript is happy since I installed the type definitions:

`npm install --save-dev @types/cordova-sqlite-storage`.

Comment: how do you import the sqlite plugin?
I am getting error "index.d.ts is not a module"